# Conventions in separating test folders

Tags: java, conventions, project-layout

Working on Java projects, it is widely accepted that you should use a standard project layout. That is the standard template you find on many open source projects, i.e.

- src/main/java
- src/main/sass
- src/main/test
- src/main/resources
- src/anotherModule/kotlin

Now, it is assumed that all tests fall under `src/main/test`. I have seen this everywhere.

Now suppose you want to [separate unit from integration tests](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340347/should-i-separate-unit-tests-and-integration-tests) so that they will not run together in CI. Is there any widely accepted convention about project layouts for integration and/or automated E2E tests?

In general, is it correct to state that I should plan to store tests so that all those under the same folder will run in the same test execution? That means if I have multiple suites, each should have its own root folder. And again, is there any known and accepted convention that integrates with popular build tools and makes testing experience seamless?

I couldn't quickly identify any in most popular open source frameworks.

Comment: The standard package layout is `src/test/<lang>`, not `src/main/test`: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html. That suggests `src/it` for integration tests.